# Factorial in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do in the Ruby program the summation of a factorial. and I can not solve. a clarification, when they run out points .... means that the logic is fine. if you get a F in one of the points, it means that the logic is wrong.

Write a program to calculate the sum of 1 + 1 / (2!) + 1 / (3!) + 1 / (4!) + .... + 1 / (n!) For a given n. Write the program in two ways: using While, For

```
def factorial(n)
#(n == 0) ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1)
fact = 1
for i in 1..n
  fact = fact * i
end
return fact
end

def sumatoriaWhile(n)
 total = n
 sumatoria = 0.0
 while n > 1
 total = total * (n - 1)
 n = n - 1
 sumatoria =sumatoria + total.to_f
 end
 return (1 + (1 / total.to_f)).round(2)
end

def sumatoriaFor(n)
 fact = 1
 sumatoria = 0.0
 for i in 1..n
  for j in 1..i
    fact = fact * j
  end
  sumatoria = sumatoria + (1 / fact.to_f)
  i = i + 1
 end
 return sumatoria.round(2)
end

#--- zona de test ----

def test_factorial
print validate(120, factorial(5)) 
print validate(5040, factorial(7)) 
print validate(362880, factorial(9)) 
end

def test_sumatoriaWhile
 print validate(1.50, sumatoriaWhile(2))
 print validate(1.83, sumatoriaWhile(3))
end

def test_sumatoriaFor
 print validate(1.50, sumatoriaFor(2))
 print validate(1.83, sumatoriaFor(3))
end

def validate (expected, value)
 expected == value ? "." : "F"
end

def test 
 puts "Test program"
 puts "---------------------------"
 test_factorial
 test_sumatoriaWhile
 test_sumatoriaFor
 puts " "
end

test
```

Comment: [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (a.k.a. `inject`) is often the method of choice for summing a series. Here: `(1..n).reduce([0.0,1]) { |(tot,fact),i| f = i*fact; [tot+1.0/f, f] }.first`.  For `n=3`, this returns `1.666...`, which (though different from what you have) I believe is correct. (Note `1.0/3! = 1.0/6 = 0.1666...`.)

Comment: Thanks Cary for the prompt reply. I need While learning a procedure, in which I posted my procedure, I want to know if is right or wrong.

Comment: @Croelanjr See my update, you should get a better understanding of how ruby works by looking at the functions. The problem is not related to ruby, imo, it seems you are not calculating the factorial correctly.

Comment: Cary. I've modified the program, I have already changed the results. according to your comment, you are using inject. I ask for help with while, do a program of factorial sum using with while. I want to see the process, I want as it does. I Querio know what the difference while and for

Comment: I understand, which is why I posted a comment rather than an answer. Glad to be of help...

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time figuring out what you're doing in the summation function. Here's a straightforward function:

```
def sumatoriaFor(n)
  return 0 if n <= 0
  factorial = 1
  sum = 0.0
  for i in 1..n
    factorial *= i
    sum += 1.0 / factorial.to_f
  end
  return sum.round(2)
end

def sumatoriaWhile(n)
  return 0 if n <= 0
  i = 1
  factorial = 1
  sumatoria = 0.0
  while i <= n
   factorial *= i
   sumatoria += (1.0 / factorial.to_f)
   i = i + 1
  end
  return sumatoria.round(2)
end
```

The while look is straight forward too now. Also your validation is wrong:

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/6 ~= 1 + 0.5 + 0.17 = 1.67
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, Thank you for your prompt response. First of all, I appreciate the help given. I am learning ruby programming and want to learn more as you and the other people. if indeed the answer is wrong. I have modified the answer. and also need to know what the function of While. and I hereby amended program again. and now I get an F on the part of WHILE.

```
def factorial(n)
fact = 1
for i in 1..n
  fact = fact * i
end
return fact
end

def sumatoriaWhile(n)
 total = n
 sumatoria = 0.0
while n < 1
 total = total * (n - 1)
 sumatoria = sumatoria + (1.0 / total.to_f)
 n = n - 1
end
return sumatoria.round(2)
end

def sumatoriaFor(n)
  fact = 1
  sumatoria = 0.0
  for i in 1..n
     fact = fact * i
     sumatoria = sumatoria + (1.0 / fact.to_f)
  end
  return sumatoria.round(2)
end

#--- zona de test ----

def test_factorial
print validate(120, factorial(5)) 
print validate(5040, factorial(7)) 
  print validate(362880, factorial(9)) 
end

def test_sumatoriaWhile
print validate(1.50, sumatoriaWhile(2))
print validate(1.67, sumatoriaWhile(3))
end

def test_sumatoriaFor
print validate(1.50, sumatoriaFor(2))
print validate(1.67, sumatoriaFor(3))
end

def validate (expected, value)
expected == value ? "." : "F"
end

def test 
puts "Test de prueba del programa"
puts "---------------------------"
test_factorial
test_sumatoriaWhile
test_sumatoriaFor
puts " "
end

test
```

Comment: You really should not use answers to give your feedback. Comments will do.

Comment: What kind of comment are you talking about me? I have only posted the modified code for the replies. and I'm also new to the forum. I want to learn Ruby. and also I need as the sum is in while.

Comment: Friend. Sorry ... what happens did not see the full post. When I first walked into this place. and surprise I saw on the tray what habias sent me.  Sorry..